# Redirecting to a particular page

Tags: css, redirect, web, html

```html
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <!-- Basic Page Needs
        ================================================== -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
        <title>Timer Agency Template</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
        ================================================== -->
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <!-- Template CSS Files
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Twitter Bootstrs CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Ionicons Fonts Css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css">
        <!-- animate css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <!-- Hero area slider css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">
        <!-- owl craousel css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
        <!-- template main css file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <!-- responsive css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
        
        <!-- Template Javascript Files
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- modernizr js -->
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- owl carouserl js -->
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <!-- bootstrap js -->

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- wow js -->
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <!-- slider js -->
        <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
        <!-- template main js -->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
        ==================================================
        Header Section Start
        ================================================== -->
        <header id="top-bar" class="navbar-fixed-top animated-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- responsive nav button -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- /responsive nav button -->
                    
                    <!-- logo -->
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a href="index.html" >
                            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /logo -->
                </div>
                <!-- main menu -->
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                    <div class="main-menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html" >Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="service.html">Log In</a></li>
                            
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- /main nav -->
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <!--
        ==================================================
        Slider Section Start
        ================================================== -->
        <section id="hero-area" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <div class="block wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                            
                            <!-- Slider -->
                            <section class="cd-intro">
                                <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated cd-headline slide" data-wow-delay=".4s" >
                                <span>EMPLOYEE TRAINING PROGRAMME</span><br>
                                <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
                                    <b class="is-visible">(ETP)</b>
                                    <b>DEVELOPER</b>
                                    <b>FATHER</b>
                                </span>
                                </h1>
                                </section> <!-- cd-intro -->
                                <!-- /.slider -->
                                
                                <a class="btn-lines dark light wow fadeInUp animated smooth-scroll btn btn-default btn-green" data-wow-delay=".9s" href="#works" data-section="#works" >View Programmes</a>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section><!--/#main-slider-->
            <!--
            ==================================================
            Slider Section Start
            ================================================== -->
            <section id="about">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="block wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                                <h2>
                                ABOUT THE COMPANY
                                </h2>
                                <p>
                                    Persistent Systems is a technology services company which was incorporated on 16 May 1990 as Persistent Systems Private Limited. It was subsequently converted into a public Limited company on 17 September 2010 with the name Persistent Systems Limited and a new certificate of incorporation was issued on 28 September 2007 from the RoC.
                                </p>
                              </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                                <img src="images/about/about.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section> <!-- /#about -->
            <!--
            ==================================================
            Portfolio Section Start
            ================================================== -->
            <section id="works" class="works">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h1 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s">Available Programmes</h1>
                        <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                            The following programmes are available for our employees..
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated portfolio-item" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="0ms">
                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                    <img src="images/portfolio/item-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" >
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a target="_blank" href="service.html">Enroll for Selenium</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <figcaption>
                                <h4>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Selenium
                                </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                     Automated software testing tool
                                </p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                    <img src="images/portfolio/item-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" >
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a target="_blank" href="service.html">Enroll for Robotium</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <figcaption>
                                <h4>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Robotium
                                </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
Automation testing framework (Android)                                </p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                    <img src="images/portfolio/item-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a target="_blank" href="service.html">Enroll for TestComplete</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <figcaption>
                                <h4>
                                <a href="#">
                                    TestComplete
                                </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    Open testing platform
                                </p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                    <img src="images/portfolio/item-4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a target="_blank" href="service.html">Enroll for SoapUI</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <figcaption>
                                <h4>
                                <a href="#">
                                    SoapUI
                                </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    Web service testing application
                                </p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="900ms">
                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                    <img src="images/portfolio/item-5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a target="_blank" href="service.html">Enroll for QTP(HP)</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <figcaption>
                                <h4>
                                <a href="#">
                                    QTP
                                </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    Automated functional testing tool
                                </p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1200ms">
                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                    <img src="images/portfolio/item-6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a target="_blank" href="service.html">Enroll for TestDrive</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <figcaption>
                                <h4>
                                <a href="#">
                                    TestDrive
                                </a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    Automated software quality solution
                                </p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section> <!-- #works -->
            <!--
            ==================================================
            Portfolio Section Start
            ================================================== -->
            <section id="feature">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h1 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s">BENEFITS</h1>
                        <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                            The benefits of the programme are clearly very high.<br>The programme empowers you with new ways for quality software development.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">Better product quality
</h4>
<p>After the programme,the products you generate will see a rise in quality.</p>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="ion-ios-lightbulb-outline"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">Client satisfaction
</h4>
                                    <p>Better quality products will automatically lead to better client satisfaction</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="900ms">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="ion-ios-lightbulb-outline"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">Work reduction
</h4>
                                    <p>The programme will allow you to generate products in a complete new mannner thus reducing your work.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1200ms">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="ion-ios-americanfootball-outline"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">Easier development
</h4>
                                    <p>Development of new products will now be easier than ever before.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1500ms">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="ion-ios-keypad-outline"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">Increased work rate
</h4>
                                    <p>New methods will allow you to work at a faster pace thus increasing your work rate.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1800ms">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="ion-ios-barcode-outline"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">Skill upgradation</h4>
                                    <p>Last but not the least,you will have a new set of skills completely industry relevant.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section> <!-- /#feature -->
                            
            <!--
            ==================================================
            Call To Action Section Start
            ================================================== -->
            <section id="call-to-action">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="block">
                                <h2 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">STILL THINKING?</h1>
                                <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration="500ms">Stop thinking. Begin now. The later you begin, the more you will be left behind.</p>
                                <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-default btn-contact wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".7s" data-wow-duration="500ms">Contact With Me</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!--
            ==================================================
            Footer Section Start
            ================================================== -->
            <footer id="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p class="copyright">Copyright: <span>2015</span> . `enter code here`Design and Developed by <a href="http://www.Themefisher.com">Themefisher</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <!-- Social Media -->
                        <ul class="social">
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PersistentSystems/" target="_blank"class="Facebook">
                                    <i class="ion-social-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/Persistentsys?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" target="_blank" class="Twitter">
                                    <i class="ion-social-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/persistent-systems" class="Linkedin" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer> <!-- /#footer -->
                
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am currently working on a web project where if the user wants to enroll for a particular program the user clicks on enroll and they are redirected to the log in page. but I want that they should be automatically redirected to their profile pages if they are already logged in.What should I do.Also I am a newbie to stackoverflow so I don't know how to present my code here.If someone would tell me how to do so I am totally open to do it.

Comment: You need code and more information; copy and paste the code in and tell us what language you have wrote the authentication in.

Comment: Tap on the "question mark" icon in the post editor for information about how you can properly input your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test in PHP if your user is logged into your website.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['isLogged'])){
    header('Location: profil.php');
    exit;
}
else {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

I suppose you don't know a lot PHP, so you should have a look to how create a membership and use PHP sessions :-)

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/user-membership-with-php--net-1523

Comment: Why do you assume he uses PHP (or wants to use) in the first place?

Comment: 90% of NEW web developpers use PHP to learn to create something like a blog or a simple membership. Op didn't give more informations so it's probably PHP, but the logic is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

well you need to check your if session or if cookie exists and is not expired .... if they exist then you redirect  before the whole page is loaded (server Logic) ... as i dont know what language you have written you server logic in i cant help you with the code

Answer (score 0):

After user is logged-in generate a user token and store it in a cookie when ever user redirect to login-page use jquery/javascript to check the cookie then from there you can decide whether user should stay in login-page or redirect to profile page. 
You can post your code by pasting in the editor and select the code then click on `{}` this symbol